# Store stream volume and restore it after service

Tags: java, android, eclipse, media-player

I have an android app that changes the users ringer preference or notification volume when music is playing.

Is there a way that I can store their current volume settings across all streams and restore it when my service is killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used getStreamVolume(); to get the volume and I then stored the value until the service was killed. After the service was killed I used setStreamVolume(); to return the volume to the stored setting.

[Android Reference - getStreamVolume();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29)